# Empty array is not saved to DynamoDB table using Dynogels + Joi

Tags: node.js, database, amazon-dynamodb, joi, dynogels

I'm trying to save an item to DynamoDB table using dynogels Orm with joi for types.
One of the properties of the saved item is `files` which is an array.
Initially, I would like this value to be an empty array.

```
const projectSchema: SchemaType = {
  name: joi.string().optional(),
  description: joi.string().optional().allow(null, ""),
  **files: joi.array().default([ ]),**
  user: joi.alternatives().try(joi.object(), joi.string()).required(),
  config: joi.object().optional(),
  background: joi.string().optional().allow(null, ""),
  status: joi.string().optional(),
  metadata: joi.object(),
  key: joi.string().optional(),
  email: joi.string().optional(),
  published: joi.boolean().default(true),
};
```

ive tried as seen above, and also by chaining other functions like `valid()`, `allow()`.
also ive tried to remove the `array()` and replaced it with `any()` but nothing seems to work. The item is being saved to the database without the files.

Is there anyone who had experience with that?

Answer (score 0):

I've not used nor heard of `dynogels` before, but it seems to be a fork of Vogels which does not support list types: https://github.com/clarkie/dynogels#schema-types

Seems you need to either use a number-set of string-set, and if this assumption on dynogels is correct, and you must use a set, DynamoDB does not allow empty sets. You would have to store an empty string within the set: `[""]`